Unable to use terraform for_each block for azurerm_api_management_api
I have two open api docs lets call them openapione.yaml and other is openapitwo.yaml. Now i am using for_each block but somehow it doesn't work for my terraform code. All i want is it should pick respective values everytime for separate openapi docs.
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
  for_each = var.apimanagement
  name                = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  revision            = each.value["revision"]
  display_name        = each.value["display_name"]
  path                = each.value["path"]
  protocols           = each.value["protocols"]
       
  import {
    content_format = each.value["content_format"]
    content_value  = each.value["content_value"]
  }
}

Below is the variable file.
variable "apimanagement" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    api_management_1 = {
      name = "flight-health"
      revision            = "1"
      display_name        = "flt-health"
      path                = "extranet/v1"
      protocols           = ["https"]
      content_format      = "openapi"
      content_value       = 'file("${path.module}/openapione.yaml")'
    }
    api_management_2 = {
      name = "availabilities"
      revision            = "2"
      display_name        = "avail"
      path                = "extranet/v1"
      protocols           = ["http"]
      content_format      = "openapi"
      content_value       = 'file("${path.module}/openapitwo.yaml")'
    }
  }
}


You cannot call the built-in functions in variable definitions the way you are trying to. This can be fixed by using the following code:
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
  for_each            = var.apimanagement
  name                = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  revision            = each.value["revision"]
  display_name        = each.value["display_name"]
  path                = each.value["path"]
  protocols           = each.value["protocols"]
    
  import {
    content_format = each.value["content_format"]
    content_value  = file("${path.module}/${each.value["content_value"]")
  }
}

and by fixing the variable to look like the following:
variable "apimanagement" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    api_management_1 = {
      name           = "flight-health"
      revision       = "1"
      display_name   = "flt-health"
      path           = "extranet/v1"
      protocols      = ["https"]
      content_format = "openapi"
      content_value  = "openapione.yaml"
    }
    api_management_2 = {
      name           = "availabilities"
      revision       = "2"
      display_name   = "avail"
      path           = "extranet/v1"
      protocols      = ["http"]
      content_format = "openapi"
      content_value  = "openapitwo.yaml"
    }
  }
}

